# Concatenating strings having dot(period) in php

Tags: php, string

Googled but couldn't find an answer.

I have

```
echo "<input type = 'text' value = ".$value." name = ".$input_id."/>";
```

`$value` or `$input_id` contains a dot which is conflicting with the dot used for concatenation. How do I escape it?

Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the concatenation operator! You just need to concatenate your strings right: `echo "<input type = 'text' value = '".$value."' name = '".$input_id."'/>";` <- see the single quotes

Comment: echo "<input type = 'text' value = '$value' name = '$input_id'/>";

Comment: use echo "<input type = 'text' value = "{$value}" name = "{$input_id}"/>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variables contains eg. space, they has to be in quotes. Concat operators cause no problem.

```
echo "<input type='text' value='" . $value . "' name='" . $input_id . "'/>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
echo "<input type='text' value='" . $value . "' name='" . $input_id . "'/>";
```