# HTML input into SQL query using PHP after a button click

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I want to get user-input by HTML form input field and then send this input into the SQL query.
I have tried the method I googled but there's no value selected.
The SQL query worked when I gave the value directly in the SQL query.

```
<body>
  <div class="testbox">
    <form action="train.php" method="POST">

      <div class="item">
        <div class="train-item">
          <p>Departure Station </p>
          <input type="text" name="depart" required />
        </div>

        <div class="train-item">
          <p>Arrival Station</p>
          <input type="text" name="arrive" required />
        </div>

      <div class="btn-block">
        <button type="submit" name="search" href="/">Search</button>
      </div>
  </div>
  </form>
  </div>

    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['search'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
      $depart = $_POST["depart"];
      $arrive = $_POST["arrive"];
      $sql = "SELECT ttype.TyName, train.TraNo, a.StaName dsta, c.Time dtime ,b.StaName asta , d.Time atime 
                      FROM (((((ttype RIGHT JOIN train
                      ON ttype.TyNo=train.TyNo)
                      RIGHT JOIN pass c
                      ON train.TraNo=c.TraNo)
                      RIGHT JOIN station a
                      ON a.StaNo=c.StaNo)
                      RIGHT JOIN pass d
                      ON train.TraNo=d.TraNo)
                      RIGHT JOIN station b
                      ON b.StaNo=d.StaNo)      

                      WHERE c.Time < d.Time
                      AND a.StaName='.$depart' 
                      AND b.StaName='.$arrive' ";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die("can't reach" . mysqli_error( ));
            $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);    
            $cols = mysqli_num_fields( $result); 

            $train_table = "";
            $train_table .= "This query has ". $rows ." data";
        $train_table .= ",and include". $cols ."columns";
        ?>
```

The above code showed "This query has 0 data, and includes 6 columns.

EDIT:
Thanks for helping and informing me about the SQL injection.
It's for a term-project for a course at university. The result will only be shown to my classmates and professor and I am the only one who will be access to the whole system. Thanks again.

The reason I posted my own question is that I am not familiar with PHP nor HTTP language and couldn't find the exact problem with my code. In other words, I am not sure the problem is located in the HTTP part or the PHP part.

Comment: share your db structure for the tables and what output you require. Only then we can suggest you anything

Comment: plz check my answer and let me know if your query is working now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement)

Comment: @Dharman Thanks for the information. The reason I posted my own question is that I am not familiar with PHP language and couldn't find the exact problem with my code. In other words, I am not sure the problem is located in the HTTP part or the PHP part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your DB structure. As you are saying query is working in MYSQL, try the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT ttype.TyName, train.TraNo, a.StaName dsta, c.Time dtime ,b.StaName asta , d.Time atime 
FROM (((((ttype RIGHT JOIN train
ON ttype.TyNo=train.TyNo)
RIGHT JOIN pass c
ON train.TraNo=c.TraNo)
RIGHT JOIN station a
ON a.StaNo=c.StaNo)
RIGHT JOIN pass d
ON train.TraNo=d.TraNo)
RIGHT JOIN station b
ON b.StaNo=d.StaNo)      

WHERE c.Time < d.Time
AND a.StaName = '".$depart."' 
AND b.StaName='".$arrive."'";
```

> Issue is here:

```
AND a.StaName='.$depart' AND b.StaName='.$arrive' ";
```

You can check more detail for concatenation at:
[Concatenating strings having dot(period) in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29361238/concatenating-strings-having-dotperiod-in-php)

> Its also not good to use above code which is prone to SQL Injection.
>   Try Prepared statements. You can get a very basic tutorial here:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59483442/display-single-column-mysql-data-in-multiple-columns-in-php-html/59483509#59483509
Hi! I have provided a reference photo in this question.

Comment: I got it. Try the above answer and check if it works.. just change your SQL query in code as written above in my answer..  @naomi

Comment: Please don't post answers only pointing out a typographical issue or a missing character. Such answers are unlikely to help future visitors since they are specific to OP's code. Instead, flag or vote to close the question as off-topic as per the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

try without point in query

```
WHERE c.Time < d.Time
    AND a.StaName='$depart' 
    AND b.StaName='$arrive' ";
```

Comment: Please don't post answers only pointing out a typographical issue or a missing character. Such answers are unlikely to help future visitors since they are specific to OP's code. Instead, flag or vote to close the question as off-topic as per the [help/on-topic].